# What is the difference set-based and agile development?

Tags: methodology

I have been trying to find a conclusive article to show the difference between set-based and agile development, but the both sound like same to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are very similar approaches to the same sort of problem. Agile was invented in the software development world, whereas set-based development is related to constraint theory and comes from the management world.